# GCC register optimization

Tags: c, gcc, assembly

Hi
I was interested in what assembly code will gcc generate from this code (this is just dummy code to illustrate my point):

```
int a = 0;
int foo(void)
{
    int result = a;
    a += 2;
    return result;
}
```

I was surprized that gcc copies the variable a to the stack and then from the stack to a register so it can return it. When I added register to the declaration of result, it optimized the code not to use the stack but instead to copy the variable directly to a register. I know this doesn't really make any difference but I was wondering is there any good reason why gcc doesn't make such optimization implicitly. I hope I made it clear what I am talking about...

Any ideas?

Comment: You should provide compiler version, command-lines and assembly output.

Comment: +1 for Pascal's remark. When talking about such specifics as compiler optimization, give people here as much context as possible. (That said, it just sounds to me like you weren't using the most aggressive optimizations.)

Comment: The most important part here is likely whether you compiled this code with or without optimization enabled

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When compiling Debug builds (i.e., with optimizations off), compilers tend to make very straightforward, easily debuggable code.  In this case, it might mean keeping all variables in memory / stack, rather than in registers.

Try compiling with full optimizations (-O3) and see if that makes a difference.